# Run Method not working

Tags: android, serial-port

I have a program which communicates with the serial port. I have written it in a thread

```
 public void beginListenForData()
    {

        //final byte delimiter = 10; //This is the ASCII code for a newline character
        stopWorker = false;
        readBufferPosition = 0;
        readBuffer = new byte[1024];

       workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
          public void run()
            {           
                while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker)
                {
                    try 
                    {

                        int bytesAvailable = mmInStream.available();                        
                        if(bytesAvailable > 0)
                        {
                        byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                        mmInStream.read(packetBytes);
                        for(int i=0;i<bytesAvailable;i++)
                        {
                            //byte b = packetBytes[i];

                        byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                    System.arraycopy(packetBytes, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                    final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                readBufferPosition = 0;

                    handler.post(new Runnable()
                    {
                     public void run()
                    {
                                  Volt.setText(data);
                }
                    });

                    }

                }//End of if
            } 
            catch (IOException ex) 
            {
                stopWorker = true;
            }
        }//End of while
      }//End of run
   });//End of workerThread

   workerThread.start();
   }//End of function begin Listen For Data
```

But in my program the run method not working .I first tried to display a letter ' k' before displaying data.But whatever I write in the run method doesn't do anything.  Is there any requirement that should be added to the manifest file before writing the thread? I don't even know if my while loop works or not.

This is my logcat:

```
12-20 10:11:09.110: D/dalvikvm(4777): GC_CONCURRENT freed 207K, 5% free 6724K/7047K,     paused 4ms+8ms
12-20 10:13:59.410: W/dalvikvm(4777): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught           exception (group=0x40a401f8)
12-20 10:13:59.450: E/AndroidRuntime(4777): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-184
12-20 10:13:59.450: E/AndroidRuntime(4777): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
12-20 10:13:59.450: E/AndroidRuntime(4777):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4039)
12-20 10:13:59.450: E/AndroidRuntime(4777):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChild(ViewRootImpl.java:722)
12-20 10:13:59.450: E/AndroidRuntime(4777):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:771)
12-20 10:13:59.450: E/AndroidRuntime(4777):     at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4005)
12-20 10:13:59.450: E/AndroidRuntime(4777):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:8515)
12-20 10:13:59.450: E/AndroidRuntime(4777):     at android.widget.TextView.invalidateRegion(TextView.java:4383)
12-20 10:13:59.450: E/AndroidRuntime(4777):     at android.widget.TextView.invalidateCursor(TextView.java:4325)
12-20 10:13:59.450: E/AndroidRuntime(4777):     at android.widget.TextView.spanChange(TextView.java:7725)
12-20 10:13:59.450: E/AndroidRuntime(4777):     at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onSpanAdded(TextView.java:8074)
12-20 10:13:59.450: E/AndroidRuntime(4777):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendSpanAdded(SpannableStringBuilder.java:909)
12-20 10:13:59.450: E/AndroidRuntime(4777):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:614)
12-20 10:13:59.450: E/AndroidRuntime(4777):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:520)
12-20 10:13:59.450: E/AndroidRuntime(4777):     at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:76)
12-20 10:13:59.450: E/AndroidRuntime(4777):     at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:87)
12-20 10:13:59.450: E/AndroidRuntime(4777):     at android.text.method.ArrowKeyMovementMethod.initialize(ArrowKeyMovementMethod.java:304)
12-20 10:13:59.450: E/AndroidRuntime(4777):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3294)
12-20 10:13:59.450: E/AndroidRuntime(4777):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3162)
12-20 10:13:59.450: E/AndroidRuntime(4777):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:78)
12-20 10:13:59.450: E/AndroidRuntime(4777):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3137)
12-20 10:13:59.450: E/AndroidRuntime(4777):     at com.example.demo.MainActivity$6.run(MainActivity.java:505)
12-20 10:13:59.450: E/AndroidRuntime(4777):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-20 10:14:00.640: D/OpenGLRenderer(4777): Flushing caches (mode 0)
12-20 10:14:01.560: D/OpenGLRenderer(4777): Flushing caches (mode 1)
12-20 10:14:01.620: E/ActivityThread(4777): Activity com.example.demo.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.example.demo.MainActivity$4@410bc160 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
12-20 10:14:01.620: E/ActivityThread(4777): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.example.demo.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.example.demo.MainActivity$4@410bc160 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
12-20 10:14:01.620: E/ActivityThread(4777):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:763)
12-20 10:14:01.620: E/ActivityThread(4777):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:567)
12-20 10:14:01.620: E/ActivityThread(4777):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1043)
12-20 10:14:01.620: E/ActivityThread(4777):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1030)
12-20 10:14:01.620: E/ActivityThread(4777):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1024)
12-20 10:14:01.620: E/ActivityThread(4777):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:341)
12-20 10:14:01.620: E/ActivityThread(4777):     at com.example.demo.MainActivity.searchDevices(MainActivity.java:230)
12-20 10:14:01.620: E/ActivityThread(4777):     at com.example.demo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:93)
12-20 10:14:01.620: E/ActivityThread(4777):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
12-20 10:14:01.620: E/ActivityThread(4777):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
12-20 10:14:01.620: E/ActivityThread(4777):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
12-20 10:14:01.620: E/ActivityThread(4777):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
12-20 10:14:01.620: E/ActivityThread(4777):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
12-20 10:14:01.620: E/ActivityThread(4777):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
12-20 10:14:01.620: E/ActivityThread(4777):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-20 10:14:01.620: E/ActivityThread(4777):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-20 10:14:01.620: E/ActivityThread(4777):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
12-20 10:14:01.620: E/ActivityThread(4777):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-20 10:14:01.620: E/ActivityThread(4777):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-20 10:14:01.620: E/ActivityThread(4777):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-20 10:14:01.620: E/ActivityThread(4777):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-20 10:14:01.620: E/ActivityThread(4777):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post the stacktrace. i suspect a crash

Comment: You cannot update UI in thread so this line  Volt.setText("Bluetooth Opened");   will give you error

Answer (score 1):

`Volt.setText("Bluetooth Opened");`

Updating ui on the thread is wrong. Need to update ui on ui thread. Probably your app crashes.

Comment: @treesa what is Volt a textview or edittext or button. updating those on the thread's run method causes a exception.

Comment: it is a text view but when i remove that line again it is not working

Comment: @treesa post the stack trace for further help and you don't see this  `Volt.setText(data);`

Comment: @treesa  Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. this is clear update ui from ui thread so the first exception is bcoz of updating ui from a backgroudn thread. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?. You need to unregister in onPause or onStop. using broadcast receiver??

Answer (score 1):

You cannot update UI in thread so this line `Volt.setText("Bluetooth Opened");` will give you error